# XSLT Match Items With Class

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I'm doing a fairly simple XSLT template, and seem to have something wrong.

I'm trying to loop through each  element in a HTML table, and if it has a particular class, then it should print something and if not, it should print something else.

An excerpt of the HTML. I want to match an  with the class "instructionRow".

```
                  <tr role="row" class="odd">
                    <td>1</td><td class="itemCell">Burger</td>
                    <td>15.00</td>
                    <td>Mains</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr role="row" class="even instructionRow">
                    <td class="invisibleText">1</td>
                    <td class="itemCell">No Pineapple</td>
                    <td>1.50</td><td class="invisibleText"></td>
                  </tr>
```

This here is the XSL I'm trying:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" doctype-public="XSLT-compat" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
<xsl:template match="/">
<order timestamp="{current-dateTime()}">
<xsl:for-each select="table/tbody/tr">
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="//tr[contains(@class, 'instructionRow')]">
        Instruction
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        Not Instruction
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:for-each>
</order>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

However the test seems to always return positive and print "Instruction" even when I set the string to match to be...anything. On the above example, the result after transformation should be

```
Not Instruction

Instruction
```

A fiddle: http://xsltransform.net/6qtmFHd

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within

```
<xsl:for-each select="table/tbody/tr">
```

the current node is a `tr`.  So, change

```
<xsl:when test="//tr[contains(@class, 'instructionRow')]">
```

(which checks not the current `tr` but every `tr` in the document) to

```
<xsl:when test="contains(@class, 'instructionRow')">
```

in order to test each `tr/@class` iterated by the loop.